# Converting 0xFF to RGB value

Tags: java, rgb, processing, hex

I have a snippet of code I am using for a Java application, I am trying to replace the hex value of 0xFF which equals blue to a different color preferably represented by an RGB value, is this possible?

```
void trailBlurEffect(int blendAmount, PGraphics buffer) {
   for (int i = 0, y = 0; y < buffer.height; y++) {
     for (int x = 0; x < buffer.width; x++, i++) {
       buffer.pixels[i] = 0xff000000 | (( buffer.pixels[i]  & 0xFF) * blendAmount) >> 8;
     }
   }
   nodeBuffer.updatePixels();
}
```

edit: 
I am trying to write a different color however I am unable to get a result that works, for example by replacing 0xFF(blue) with the hex equivalent of red which is = 0xFF0000 my canvas draws nothing. My code is coming from this example: openprocessing.org/sketch/52388

Comment: Have you tried? Are you having any issues?

Comment: I am trying to convert 0xFF to a different color other than blue, if I use a converter for lets say red it equals FF0000 in hex format which does not work.

Comment: This is kind of like saying you are trying to convert the number 2 into the number 3. It's not clear what you trying to accomplish. If you want to write a different color: write a different color.

Comment: @user813611: That is more clear, thanks. You should edit the question with these improvements above though.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty unclear on what you're trying to accomplish.  RGB colors are given as three different numbers: A Red, Green, and a Blue value.  Each value can range from 0 - 255.  0xFF isn't an RGB value, it's a value representing one of the colors.  To get a full RGB color, you would have to use something like 0xFF0000.  So no, you can't magically turn 0xFF into Blue, you have to know the values of the other colors as well.  You could take in three values, and then formulate the color from there, IE take in a rValue, gValue, and bValue, then stick 'em all together to get the classic RGB format of 0xRRGGBB.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don'y know binary math, but i think this is what is being done in

```
  buffer.pixels[i]  & 0xFF
```

0xFF is a mask to be applied to buffer.pixels[i]. So this is not the way you will get the color you need. You can try calling fill(wantedColor) just before ellipse() in draw(), but as author said in the page you pointed, for the trail he only used the blue channel i think the trail will still be blue.